# Prevent Entity Framework with postgreSQL changing timezone when retrieving data

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with PostgreSQL. I have a big problem when retrieving timestamp with timezone data.

The value in the database (timestampwithtimezone type) is `2021-06-17 15:00:00.567379+07` (hour: 15, timezone: +7)

My computer has timezone -2, when I use LINQ to entity, the result (DateTimeOffset C#) is "17/06/2021 6:00:00 AM -02:00" (hour is changed to 6 and timezone is -2).

I want to keep original timezone, it is important for me. Is there any config?

I installed some nugets:

- Npgsql 5.0.3
- EntityFramework6.Npgsql 6.4.3

This error is not appear when I use entity framework with SQL Server.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Column types, class properties - everything is needed.

Comment: Those date/times are the same. The offsets are not timezones.

Comment: DataTime object are transferred between machines as a number in UTC and then display on your local machine in local time.  You cannot get the original machines timezone from just the date object.  The database is showning the date in the timezone where the database is located which is in a different timezone from the machine you are using.

Comment: This error is not appear when I use entity framework with SQL Server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29133922/5045688